# End User defined Controls and calculations on WinForm. Thoughts on speed?

Tags: c#

Users can define custom controls that are added to an entry form at run-time. The values of these controls are later stored in a MySQL database. Optionally, users can define 'recipes' to auto calculate some controls.

For an example, a user could enter Gross and Tare weight and use a FieldCalc for the Net Weight. In this case the ValueChanged event of both Gross and Tare will call FieldCalcValueChanged below.

Multiple recipes could be triggered by a change to a single field. There is no loop protection/detection.

CalcTotal does the work, processing each line of the recipe, then assigning the outputs. This could cascade other recipes.

In general, the above example is the normal case. In a few cases, there are 3-6 mileage fields, which total to a single field.

The code works great. But slowly. So much so, is some cases, that users choose to disable the FieldCalc recipes, and run a 10-key, which is not acceptable.

Any suggestions for speed or otherwise are appreciated.

configfieldcalc:

```
id   fieldcalcname                                 code 
---- --------------------------------------------- ---- 
2    NetWeight                                          
6    MilesDifference                                    
5    NetScale                                           
7    MilesCalc
```

configfieldcalcstep:

```
id   configfieldcalcid step linetype output                                        operator                 valuetype option                                        notes                                         
---- ----------------- ---- -------- --------------------------------------------- ------------------------ --------- --------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------- 
2    2                 1    math     weightnet                                     math_assign              metric    weightgross                                                                                 
3    2                 2    math     weightnet                                     math_subtract            metric    weighttare                                                                                  

7    5                 1    if       factor                                        if_not_equal             number    0                                                                                           
8    5                 2    if       weightnet                                     if_not_equal             number    0                                                                                           
9    5                 3    math     scalenet                                      math_assign              metric    weightnet                                                                                   
10   5                 4    math     scalenet                                      math_multiply            number    1000.0000                                                                                   
11   5                 5    math     scalenet                                      math_divide              metric    factor                                                                                      
12   5                 6    round    scalenet                                                                         0                                                                                           
13   5                 7    endif                                                                                                                                                                                 
14   5                 8    endif                                                                                                                                                                                 

19   6                 1    if       miles                                         if_not_equal             number    0                                                                                           
20   6                 2    math     milesdifference                               math_assign              metric    miles                                                                                       
21   6                 3    math     milesdifference                               math_subtract            metric    milesWaTotal                                                                                
22   6                 4    math     milesdifference                               math_subtract            metric    milesWaOffroad                                                                              
23   6                 5    math     milesdifference                               math_subtract            metric    milesOrLoaded                                                                               
24   6                 6    math     milesdifference                               math_subtract            metric    milesOrEmpty                                                                                
25   6                 7    math     milesdifference                               math_subtract            metric    milesOrRUAF                                                                                 
26   6                 8    endif                                                                                                                                                                                 

15   7                 1    if       milesend                                      if_not_equal             number    0                                                                                           
16   7                 2    math     miles                                         math_assign              metric    milesend                                                                                    
17   7                 3    math     miles                                         math_subtract            metric    milesstart                                                                                  
18   7                 4    endif
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LoggingControls;
using LoggingUtility;

namespace TicketEntry
{
public class FieldCalc
{
    private static DataView _configFieldCalcStepView;
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITicketRateMetric> _metricControls;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Time> _timeControls;

    static FieldCalc()
    {
        SetFieldCalcStepView();
    }

    static public void SetFieldCalcStepView()
    {
        _configFieldCalcStepView = new DataView
        {
            Table = LoggingUtility.Data.ConfigFieldCalcStep(),
            Sort = "configfieldcalcid,step"
        };
    }

    public FieldCalc(IEnumerable<ITicketRateMetric> metricControls, IEnumerable<Time> timeControls)
    {
        _metricControls = metricControls;
        _timeControls = timeControls;
    }

    public void ClearEventHandlers()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<ClearEventHandlers>");
        Debug.Indent();

        foreach (ITicketRateMetric metric in _metricControls)
        {
            metric.ClearRateMetricValueChanged();
        }

        foreach (var time in _timeControls)
        {
            time.TextChanged -= FieldCalcValueChanged;
        }

        Debug.Unindent();
        Debug.WriteLine("</ClearEventHandlers>");
    }

    public void SetEventHandlers() 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<SetEventHandlers>");
        Debug.Indent();

        ClearEventHandlers();

        var stepOptions = from DataRow basisstep in _configFieldCalcStepView.Table.Rows
                          where basisstep.Field<string>("valuetype") == "metric"
                          select new
                          {
                              configfieldcalcid = basisstep.Field<uint>("configfieldcalcid"),
                              option = basisstep.Field<string>("option")
                          };

        foreach (var o in stepOptions)
        {
            try
            {
                var eo = o; //Must capture variable to avoid access to modified closure
                var metric = (from control in _metricControls
                              where control.Name == eo.option
                              select control).First();

                metric.RateMetricValueChanged += FieldCalcValueChanged;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { /* NOP */ }
        }

        stepOptions = from DataRow basisstep in _configFieldCalcStepView.Table.Rows
                      where basisstep.Field<string>("valuetype") == "time"
                      select new
                      {
                          configfieldcalcid = basisstep.Field<uint>("configfieldcalcid"),
                          option = basisstep.Field<string>("option")
                      };

        foreach (var o in stepOptions)
        {
            try
            {
                var eo = o; //Must capture variable to avoid access to modified closure
                var time = (from control in _timeControls
                            where control.Name == eo.option
                            select control).First();

                time.TextChanged += FieldCalcValueChanged;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { /* NOP */ }
        }

        Debug.Unindent();
        Debug.WriteLine("</SetEventHandlers>");
    }

    private void FieldCalcValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as Control;

        if (s != null)
        {
            CalcTotal(s.Parent.Name);
        }
    }

    private void CalcTotal(string fieldTriggered)
    {
        var output = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

        var fieldCalcId = from DataRow basisstep in _configFieldCalcStepView.Table.Rows
                          where basisstep.Field<string>("option") == fieldTriggered
                          select basisstep.Field<uint>("configfieldcalcid");

        foreach (var f in fieldCalcId)
        {
            _configFieldCalcStepView.RowFilter = string.Format("configfieldcalcid = '{0}'", f);

            var skipIfCount = 0; //Track count of IF types, to find correct matching ENDIF, when there are nested IF types 

            foreach (DataRowView step in _configFieldCalcStepView)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("LineType = " + step.Row.Field<string>("linetype"));
                BasisUtility.BasisLineType b = BasisUtility.ParseBasisLineType(step.Row.Field<string>("linetype"));

                var o = step.Row.Field<string>("output");
                if (o != string.Empty && output.ContainsKey(o) == false && (b == BasisUtility.BasisLineType.MATH || b == BasisUtility.BasisLineType.ROUND))
                {
                    output.Add(o, decimal.Zero);
                }

                switch (b)
                {
                    default:
                        break;
                    case BasisUtility.BasisLineType.ENDIF:
                        skipIfCount--;
                        break;
                    case BasisUtility.BasisLineType.MATH:
                        if (skipIfCount == 0)
                        {
                            CalcLineTypeMath(step, output);
                        }
                        break;
                    case BasisUtility.BasisLineType.IF:
                        if (skipIfCount == 0)
                        {
                            var ifPassed = CalcLineTypeIf(step, output);

                            if (!ifPassed)
                            {
                                skipIfCount++;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            skipIfCount++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case BasisUtility.BasisLineType.ROUND:
                        if (skipIfCount == 0)
                        {
                            CalcLineTypeRound(step, output);
                        }
                        break;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine("skipIfCount = " + skipIfCount);
            }

            foreach (var o in output)
            {
                var eo = o; //Must capture variable to avoid access to modified closure
                var metric = (from control in _metricControls
                              where control.Name == eo.Key
                              select control).First();

                metric.Value = o.Value;
            }

            _configFieldCalcStepView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void CalcLineTypeMath(DataRowView step, IDictionary<string, decimal> output)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<CalcLineTypeMath>");
        Debug.Indent();

        var outputVar = step.Row.Field<string>("output");
        BasisUtility.BasisOperator op = BasisUtility.ParseBasisOperator(step.Row.Field<string>("operator"));
        BasisUtility.BasisValueType valueType = BasisUtility.ParseBasisValueType(step.Row.Field<string>("valuetype"));
        var option = step.Row.Field<string>("option");

        Debug.WriteLine("outputVar = " + step.Row.Field<string>("output"));
        Debug.WriteLine("op = " + step.Row.Field<string>("operator"));
        Debug.WriteLine("valueType = " + step.Row.Field<string>("valuetype"));
        Debug.WriteLine("option = " + step.Row.Field<string>("option"));

        decimal input = CalcInput(output, valueType, outputVar, option);

        switch (op)
        {
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_ASSIGN:
                output[outputVar] = input;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_ADD:
                output[outputVar] += input;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_SUBTRACT:
                output[outputVar] -= input;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_MULTIPLY:
                output[outputVar] *= input;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_DIVIDE:
                try
                {
                    output[outputVar] /= input;
                }
                catch (DivideByZeroException)
                {
                    output[outputVar] = 1;
                }
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_POWER_OF:
                output[outputVar] = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)output[outputVar], (double)input);
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.MATH_MODULUS:
                output[outputVar] %= input;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("output[outputVar] = " + output[outputVar]);

        Debug.Unindent();
        Debug.WriteLine("</CalcLineTypeMath>");
    }

    private decimal CalcInput(IDictionary<string, decimal> output, BasisUtility.BasisValueType valueType, string outputVar, string option)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<CalcInput>");
        Debug.Indent();

        var input = decimal.Zero;
        decimal md;

        Debug.WriteLine("valueType = " + valueType);

        switch (valueType)
        {
            default:
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisValueType.ENTITY:
                //TODO add lookup for ENTITY:
                input = -2;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisValueType.METRIC:
                var o = (from m in _metricControls
                         where m.Name == option
                         select m.Value.ToString()).First();
                decimal.TryParse(o, out md);
                input = md;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisValueType.TIME:
                var t = (from m in _timeControls
                         where m.Name == option
                         select m.Value).First();

                decimal.TryParse(t.TotalHours.ToString(), out md);
                input = md;
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisValueType.INTERNAL:
                input = (option.Equals("DEFAULT")) ? decimal.Zero : output[outputVar];
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisValueType.NUMBER:
                decimal d;
                decimal.TryParse(option, out d);
                input = d;
                break;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("input = " + input);

        Debug.Unindent();
        Debug.WriteLine("</CalcInput>");

        return input;
    }

    private bool CalcLineTypeIf(DataRowView step, IDictionary<string, decimal> output)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<CalcLineTypeIf>");
        Debug.Indent();

        var outputVar = step.Row.Field<string>("output");
        BasisUtility.BasisOperator op = BasisUtility.ParseBasisOperator(step.Row.Field<string>("operator"));
        BasisUtility.BasisValueType valueType = BasisUtility.ParseBasisValueType(step.Row.Field<string>("valuetype"));
        var option = step.Row.Field<string>("option");

        Debug.WriteLine("outputVar = " + step.Row.Field<string>("output"));
        Debug.WriteLine("op = " + step.Row.Field<string>("operator"));
        Debug.WriteLine("valueType = " + step.Row.Field<string>("valuetype"));
        Debug.WriteLine("option = " + step.Row.Field<string>("option"));

        var input = CalcInput(output, valueType, outputVar, option);

        var outvalue = (output.Keys.Contains(outputVar)) ? output[outputVar] : CalcInput(output, BasisUtility.BasisValueType.METRIC, string.Empty, outputVar);

        var result = false;

        switch (op)
        {
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.IF_EQUAL:
                result = (outvalue == input);
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.IF_NOT_EQUAL:
                result = (outvalue != input);
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.IF_LESS_THAN:
                result = (outvalue < input);
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.IF_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL:
                result = (outvalue <= input);
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.IF_GREATER_THAN:
                result = (outvalue > input);
                break;
            case BasisUtility.BasisOperator.IF_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL:
                result = (outvalue >= input);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("result = " + result);

        Debug.Unindent();
        Debug.WriteLine("</CalcLineTypeIf>");

        return result;
    }

    private void CalcLineTypeRound(DataRowView step, IDictionary<string, decimal> output)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<CalcLineTypeRound>");
        Debug.Indent();

        var outputVar = step.Row.Field<string>("output");
        int decimals;
        int.TryParse(step.Row.Field<string>("option"), out decimals);

        output[outputVar] = Math.Round(output[outputVar], decimals, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        Debug.WriteLine("output[outputVar] = " + output[outputVar]);

        Debug.Unindent();
        Debug.WriteLine("</CalcLineTypeRound>");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: any idea where the bottleneck might be?

Comment: The foreach (DataRowView step in _configFieldCalcStepView) loop is called every time a digit is entered on the triggered control. So I guess the question is how I can improve the logic/speed of this section. I could move the event to validate? lostfocus? I'm not sure if that would be a better place. And truthfully, some users would not be happy with the 'delay' in updating the fields, see milesdifference in the above step list.

Answer (score 2):

Hook up a profiler and measure what exactly is causing the slow down. Everything else is basically stabbing in the dark. That being said, there are a few things you could check:

1. You have a few loops in there checking `_metricControls` and `_timeControls` frequently for one with a specific name. Store them in a dictionary keyed of the name rather than as the plain `IEnumerables`:

   ```
   public FieldCalc(IEnumerable<ITicketRateMetric> metricControls, IEnumerable<Time> timeControls)
   {
       _metricControls = metricControls.ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => c);
       _timeControls = timeControls.ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => c);
   }
   ```
2. You do a fair amount of parsing so you could look at caching it.  Caching can speed up things but comes with it's own draw backs so I'd be checking first if it's a problem or not.

The first option is cheap and will reduce some of the code complexity (`_metricControls[op.Name]` as opposed to a  multi-line LINQ statement) so I'd do it anyway.